# Laravel Cashier Without Subscription

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-cashier

I have following requirement. App user A calls another user B and if the user B attends the call, $1 has to be debited from his credit card. Card details will be collected during the registration step.

There is no subscription involved in the process. Do I need to use Laravel cashier for this?

Comment: you want to do a instant payment?

Comment: you are better with a regular payment

Comment: No need of instant payment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: You don't need to use Laravel cashier for "one-off" charges.

In their [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/billing) they were clearly mentioned following.

`If you're only performing "one-off" charges and do not offer subscriptions, you should not use Cashier. Instead, use the Stripe and Braintree SDKs directly.`